# MongoDB script execute queries stored in variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-shell

My .js script reads from a file containing mongodb queries and populates it into an array. Then I read that array and executing the queries but they are not being executed. Below is my code.

```
1. //After successfuly connecting to mongodb
2. //read a file containing queries
3. var queryFile = cat("queries.txt");
4. var queries = queryFile.split("\r\n");
5. var length = queries.length;
6. for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
7.        var start = new Date().getTime()
8.        queries[i]
9.        var end = new Date().getTime();
10.        var timeElapsed = (end - start)/1000;
11.        print ( "Time taken to run query : "+timeElapsed+" secs" )
12. }
```

It only works if I replace line 12 with an actual query e.g. db.coll.count()

Comment: `queries[i]` is just a string. My guess would be to evaluate that string with `eval(queries[i])`. Even if 'eval is evil' and stuff.

Comment: Okay that did the trick, but why is eval evil.

Comment: Oh it's an old debate. Basically, `eval` allows code injection, by running whatever's passed to it. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) and [that](https://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval)

Comment: Great, can you draft an answer then I will accept that.

Comment: Good idea :) Did so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queries[i]` is just a string. It's a stringified instruction. My guess would be to evaluate it with `eval(queries[i])`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        var start = new Date().getTime()
        eval(queries[i]);
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        var timeElapsed = (end - start)/1000;
        print ( "Time taken to run query : "+timeElapsed+" secs" )
 }
```

However, one often says that [eval is evil](https://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval) and has to be used ONLY in last resort.